# Broadcast receiver SMS/CALL не работают вне приложения

Tags: java, android

На андройд 9.0 мои броадкасты на прослушку смс и входящих звонков не работают если активити останавливается. Как сделать чтобы броадкасты работали вне приложения?

Answer (score 0):

В манифесте `Receiver` задекларировать как

```
exported=true
```

[документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#exported)

**Update**

Посмотрел свой код N-летней давности, там у меня так:

```
<!-- SMS receiver -->
<receiver
   android:name=".SmsReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true"
   android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > <!-- 999 is highest system priority, so it's hack 2147483647 -->
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> <!-- pre kitkat action -->
       <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" /> <!-- kitkat action -->
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Плюс 2 пермишена на чтение:

```
<!-- SMS handling permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: `<receiver
            android:name="detector.sakuraso13.Broadcaster.MyReceiverSms"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>`
        </receiver> у меня задекларировано но все равно

Comment: В 9 андроиде права на звонки и смс не возможно получить, они сразу сбрасываются самой системой. Если я ошибаюсь поправьте, но у меня была подобная проблема.

Comment: См. апдейт ответа. @fadey Эти ограничения касаются отправки смс, но не приемки